# How to properly position my sub-drop down menu?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm creating a 2 tier drop down, menu and sub-menu, and I'm having an issue with either positioning, relative or absolute, and or floats. I've played around with absolute and the space/gap goes away, but my sub-menu's don't fly-out next to the hovered item, only the first. I tried relative and float both produce the undesired gap, but the sub-menu fly's out next to the hovered item as I want. Here's the code where I believe is where the issue is. **Note, I created a JSFIDDLE so you can see the working code example:**

Here's the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rVec3/) that has the HTML and CSS. I put the code that has the gaps, but has the correct fly-out positioning. If I need to clarify things more clearly, let me know and I'll try.

**Troubled code - I think**

```
.sub-navigation-content {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0 0 150px;
    top: -10px;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    z-index: 999;
    visibility: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 #999;
}
```

Below are screen shots of what I want it to look like:

**Correct looking fly-out, but incorrect fly-out position:**

[image]

**Incorrect looking fly-out, but correct fly-out position:**

[image]

Thanks in advance for having a look :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So So ... You can use absolute position, but you need remove `top: -10px;`.

final class for sub-navigation-content:

```
.sub-navigation-content {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 0 0 150px;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    z-index: 999;
    visibility: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 #999;
}
```

I think its work good. And you can move fly-out list to top by change margin as you need, i e:

```
.sub-navigation-content {
    position: absolute;
    margin: -35px 0 0 150px;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    z-index: 999;
    visibility: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 #999;
}
```

Comment: I've been working on figuring this out for a while and I cannot believe it was as simple as removing `top` and adjusting the margin. Very nice work and thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just give your `.sub-navigation-content` class an absolute positioning instead of relative.

```
.sub-navigation-content {
  position: absolute;
}
```

You would surely also adjust the top to has at least a value of `0`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I've tried that before and what happens is the fly-out menu will not fly-out next to the hovered item. All the fly-outs stay in one position up top of the menu :( Check out what your suggestion looks like http://jsfiddle.net/rVec3/2/

Comment: yes, you need to remove Top, if you have value for it, fly-out for all parnt list will be stay at top.